# How do I check what is wrong in my full-adder code?

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, circuit-construction

I am trying to solve the first question on the qiskit test which is writing a code for a full adder.

So based on my research if I have $A$ `q[0]`, $B$ `q[1]` and $C$ in `q[2]` as input and `Sum` and `Cout` as output, I should be able to produce the correct outputs by the following gates:

```
q[0] XOR1 q[1] ---> q[4]

q[0] AND1 q[1] ---> q[3]

q[2] XOR2 q[4] ---> q[5] (SUM)

q[2] AND2 q[4] ---> q[6]

q[3] OR q[6] ---> q[7] (COUT)
```

Writing the following program I get that my answer is producing wrong results :

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit import IBMQ, Aer, execute

##### build your quantum circuit here

#Define registers and a quantum circuit
q = QuantumRegister(8) 
c = ClassicalRegister(2)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q,c)

# Preparing inputs
qc.x(q[0])  # Comment this line to make Qbit0 = |0>
qc.x(q[1])  # Comment this line to make Qbit1 = |0>
qc.x(q[2])  # Comment this line to make Qbit2 = |0> ( carry-in bit )
qc.barrier()

# AND gate1 implementation
qc.ccx(q[0],q[1],q[3])
qc.barrier()

# XOR gate1 implementation
qc.cx(q[0],q[4])
qc.cx(q[1],q[4])
qc.barrier()

# XOR gate2 implementation
qc.cx(q[2],q[5])
qc.cx(q[4],q[5])
qc.barrier()

# AND gate2 implementation
qc.ccx(q[2],q[4],q[6])
qc.barrier()

#OR gate implementation
qc.cx(q[3],q[7])
qc.cx(q[6],q[7])
qc.ccx(q[3],q[6],q[7])
qc.barrier()

# Measuring and put result to classical bit
# ( sum )
qc.measure(q[5],c[0])
# ( carry-out )
qc.measure(q[7],c[1])

# execute the circuit by qasm_simulator
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
job = execute(qc, backend, shots=1000)
result = job.result()
count = result.get_counts()
print(count)
qc.draw(output='mpl')
```

Grading tells me that my results are not matching, but I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code.
Thank you so much for help.

Comment: What was wrong with your result?

Comment: Maybe you can leave a hyperlink to the source website. And I'm not sure what is your carry-in qubit refers to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am correct, I suppose you are talking about the Qiskit Challenge 2020. A possible reason why your circuit is being graded wrong is because the question asks you to construct the circuit for full adder and give it the input $A=1$, $B=0$ and $X=1$. However, I think as per your code, you are preparing the qubits to be $|ABX\rangle = |111\rangle$ instead of $|101\rangle$. Baring that, your circuit works perfectly fine from what I could analyze.

Comment: Thank you so much :), yes that was the problem, silly mistake.